# How to make a list of bytes?

Tags: python, arrays, byte

To pack data for a binary network protocol, I need to convert an integer to a list of bytes for use in `struct.pack("ccc", myList)`

I've found that this does not work:
*(using `integer.to_bytes`)*

```
myData = 0x123456
packed = struct.pack("ccc", *list(myData.to_bytes(3, byteorder='little')))
```

The exception is `char format requires a bytes object of length 1`, because the list is a list of `<class 'int'>`, even though it was created by `.to_bytes()`

But this code does work:

```
myData = 0x123456
packed = struct.pack("ccc", *[bytes([x]) for x in myData.to_bytes(3, byteorder='little')])
# This uses a list-comprehension to convert myData to a list of bytes, instead of a list of integers.
```

I'm trying to understand *why* the `.to_bytes()` function gave me a list of integers, and if there is a more Pythonic way than using a lengthy list-comprehension to convert an int to a list of integer-bytes to a list of bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.to_bytes` is the Pythonic way to convert to a `bytes` object. I think what you're missing is that elements of a bytes object will be, by definition, one-byte integers

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binaryseq):

> Since `bytes` objects are sequences of integers (akin to a tuple), for a bytes object b, b[0] will be an integer, while b[0:1] will be a bytes object of length 1.

Most likely, what you want to do is use the `'B'` (unsigned char) format character. [See Python docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters)

```py
data = 0x123456
packed = struct.pack('BBB', *data.to_bytes(3, 'little'))
```

Comment: Thanks much!   switching from `"c"` to '"B"` made the code much more straightforward.